# Extend line to smoothly connect with a point

Tags: python, interpolation, spline

I have a curve that looks like this:
[image]
I have all the data points until a maximum value a_max = 903
I need to prolong this curve in the smoothest possible way with the additonal constraint that it has to reach y = 0 when k = 1000

I know that I have to probably use:

```
  from scipy.interpolate import spline
```

but I don`t see how to impose the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

IMO this is not an interpolation problem. You want to extrapolate - and ideally you know the theoretical type of curve based on the physics or whatever data you have there behind it. Should mean: if you know, that this data is a polynomial function of 2nd degree, fit it with such a function:

```
a_coeff = np.polyfit(k, a, 2)
k2 = np.arange(1001)

plt.plot(k2 , a_coeff[0]*k2**2 + a_coeff[1]*k2 + a_coeff[2], 'g')
```

And look if you're convinced...

[image]

EDIT: Parabolic fit by weighing the data such that the first point of the dataset and [1000, 0] are the most important:

```
k_forfit = np.append(k, 1000)

a_forfit = np.append(a, 0)

weight = np.ones(len(k_forfit))

weight[0] = weight[-1] = 1000

a_coeff = np.polyfit(k_forfit, a_forfit, 2, w=weight)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(k, a)

plt.plot(k2 , a_coeff[0]*k2**2 + a_coeff[1]*k2 + a_coeff[2], 'g')
```

[image]

And for comparison:

- green: without weights
- red: with weights
- blue circle: [1000, 0]

[image]

*Supplemental:*

*Code and data, which produced the graphs above:*

```
x = np.linspace(0, 903, 200)
y = -.005*(x-480)**2+1200

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y+(np.random.random(200)-.5)*100)
y2 = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)
plt.plot(np.arange(1000), y2[0]*np.arange(1000)**2 + y2[1]*np.arange(1000) +y2[2], 'g')
y2 = np.polyfit(x_forfit, y_forfit, 2, w=weight)
plt.plot(np.arange(1000), y2[0]*np.arange(1000)**2 + y2[1]*np.arange(1000) +y2[2], 'r')
plt.plot(1000, 0, 'bo')
```

Comment: That is pretty much the point. I am not sure about what it should be the theoretical curve, it could be a parabola. But I need to prolong it in the smoothest possible way to 1000, and I do not think that a 2nd degree function will be enough

Comment: This sounds like "could be a parabola" is the best guess you have so far.

Comment: I mean that It could be a prabola, not that it will surely be a prabola. Further, it is not sure that fitting with a prabola is going to give me that at x = 1000 y will be 0...

Comment: You can apply weights to the points of your data to be fitted, i.e. let `[0,0]` and `[1000,0]` be much more important than all the others. I'll edit...

Comment: Ok I see that this solves the problem of the endpoint. But right now I see also that there is a "gap" between the last data point that I currently have and the first "fitted" data point. I need that gap to be gone as well

Comment: I don't know which gap is opening applying this to your dataset, so hard to guess

Comment: There is a gap also in your example the last dot of your data and the first one of your red fitted function are not close enough.

Comment: Yes of course, but this is purely synthetical data: a perfect parabola with some random noise added, and it does _not_ go through [1000, 0]... So if your picture is the same, I'd guess that the requirement " must go through [1000, 0]" perhaps is wrong... It's a matter of decision what fits better: the 2nd order characteristic or the point at [1000, 0]